# Plot dataframe column name as label

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have 2 separate data frames, each contain data with column headers of 'W' and 'L'.  I am trying to plot them both as a bar graph using the column headers as labels on the x-axis.

I would like to have 'W' to be mapped to the bar that represents column name  'W' in the data frame and 'L' to be mapped to the bar that represents column name 'L' in the data frame.

My output and code is below.

```
inducted_df_mean = inducted_df[['W', 'L']].mean()
not_inducted_df_mean = not_inducted_df[['W', 'L']].mean()

bar_width = 0.35
bar1 = plt.bar(index, not_inducted_df_mean, bar_width, color='r', label='Not Inducted')
bar2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, inducted_df_mean, bar_width, color='g',label='Inducted')
plt.title('Average Wins and Losses for MLB Hall of Fame Pitchers')
plt.ylabel('Number of Wins/Losses')
plt.xlabel('Wins/Loses')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `tick_label` property of each bar plot like this:

```
bar1 = plt.bar(index, not_inducted_df_mean, bar_width, color='r', label='Not Inducted', tick_label=['W','L'])
```

or try setting the `plt.xticks()` like this:

```
plt.xticks( [0.0, 0.3, 1.0, 1.3], ('W', 'L', 'W', 'L') )
```

Comment: I added it and received and error message.  AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-18b41ea30c3e> in <module>()
     10 
     11 
---> 12 bar1.set_xticklabels(['W','L'])
     13 bar2.set_xticklabels(['W','L'])
     14 plt.legend()

AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'set_xticklabels'

Comment: what did you receive?

Comment: @sadAndClueless72 my fault, the bar plot doesn't return `axe`, I edited.

Comment: Ok, I  updated the code as you instructed and bar2 is graphed with the W/L on the x-axis but bar1 does not have it.

Comment: @sadAndClueless72 ok try my second proposal, I edited my answer.

Comment: I added the plt.xticks( [0.0, 0.3, 1.0, 1.3], ('W', 'L', 'W', 'L') ) and this got the job done.Thanks!

Comment: @sadAndClueless72 your welcome, glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the optional argument  tick_label of the command plt.bar.
Can you give me the form of your input tables, so that I can reproduce your graph?
It should be something like:

```
bar1 = plt.bar(..., tick_label=['W', 'L'])
```

Comment: Hi Fringant, I am not sure what you are asking me for.  Excuse my ignorance but I am new at this.

Comment: The data is imported from .csv files.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I meant: what is in inducted_df? and in not_inducted_df? But You already have an other satysfying answer I suppose.